# How to remove everything except words and dates with excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have an word file updated monthly - it contains blank rows, misc special characters that change in each report, descriptions, references and dates.
Snapshot of data from word document:
[Word document data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhaKp.jpg)

This is currently uploaded into excel and the auto_open macro opens and imports the data from word.  The macro then stops for user clean up - 
I currently use the "Filter" function to remove everything but the titles, results and dates.  If the misc special characters were constant, I could automate this, but that is not the case...
I have searched multiple forums for help and found some code that removes all except alpha characters  - it gives me the basics to start with - it removes everything except letters and then makes them all caps - I am lost on this one...

What I am currently using:

```
Sub Remove_stuff()
Dim varRange As Range
Dim varWorkRange As Range

Set varWorkRange = Range("A15:A100")
Range("a15").Select

For Each varRange In varWorkRange
    varVal = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(varRange.Value)
        vartemp = Mid(varRange.Value, i, 1)
        If Not (vartemp Like "[a-z]" Or vartemp Like "[A-Z]") Then
            varStr = ""
        Else
            varStr = UCase(vartemp)
        End If
        varVal = varVal & varStr
    Next i
    varRange.Value = varVal
Next
End Sub
```

I have searched for using "Like" with ISDATE to recognize the cells with dates and exclude them from being deleted with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated - Thanks

OK - Got it - here is the data from the word document

---

Soil Sample from south quarter (Ref “B6:D4”)

Trace Results

May 20, 2018

1

---

•   ...
Water Samples

Saline Solution

May 20, 2018

4

---

•   ...
Pesticides Used

Reference Library 4 Book C204

May 20, 2018

3
`

Comment: You could expand your character list to include lower case letters, numbers, spaces and commas (e.g. `[A-z0-9, ]`).   It is unclear from your   "Word document data example" where each cell contains an entry with line breaks or if each entry spans multiple rows.

Comment: It  would help if you included the data as an insert, not as an image and also show the expected outcome. Do you wish to exclude the numbers 1, 4, 3 for example - seems yes but would be good to know? Are the dates always in the format as shown? For example, is it always Month dd, yyyy or or can there be Month d, yyyy etc?

Comment: And Reference Library 4 Book C204 do you want only  Reference Library Book ? It helps to know what you think constitutes a word and what is expected to be retained.

Comment: Just a tip. Instead of `vartemp Like "[a-z]" Or vartemp Like "[A-Z]"`, write at the top of a module `Option Compare Text` and remove one of `Like`s.

Comment: Thomas, thanks for tip on expanding character list - very helpful

Comment: QHarr,  I've tried to put it in, but the line breaks keep going away - I'll attempt again...

Comment: QHarr, Word doc data inserted-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this :

```
Sub Remove_stuff()
Dim varRange As Range
Dim varWorkRange As Range

Set varWorkRange = Range("A15:A100")

For Each varRange In varWorkRange
    If Not IsDate(varRange) Then
        varVal = ""
        For i = 1 To Len(varRange.Value)
            vartemp = Mid(varRange.Value, i, 1)
            If Not vartemp Like "[A-z]" Then
                varStr = ""
            Else
                varStr = UCase(vartemp)
            End If
            varVal = varVal & varStr
        Next i
        varRange.Value = varVal
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

is doing the trick for me.